# Opening split editor in Eclipse plugin when two files are simultaneously selected in the project manager

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plugin to perform equivalence check on two programs. For the UI, I plan to do the following:

The user selects two files from the project explorer using ctrl+click. As soon as he selects the files, the editor is split vertically, with file_1 on one editor, and file_2 on the other. It is only after the user does this that the check_equivalence button is enabled.

I am very new to Eclipse plugin development, and have no idea of how to achieve this. The biggest problem I am facing is how to direct one file to one editor, and the other file to the other. Right now, I am splitting the editor by simulating keyboard shortcuts. Can someone help me with:

1. Getting the names of the multiple files selected.
2. Splitting the editor.
3. Directing the files to the editors.

Comment: This is too broad, you are asking too many things at once. I don't think there is an official API to split the editor area. To edit two files you need two editors open (unless the editor is specially designed to deal with multiple files).

Comment: Hi Greg. In Eclipse, there is a functionality to toggle split editor with different files by dragging a file tab to the left side of the editor window. Any way we can do it using code? If not, can you suggest some method by which I can display two files to the user simultaneously when he selects them?

Comment: That is not splitting an editor - it is splitting the editor **area** - not the same thing at all. As I said I don't think there is an API for this.

Comment: Does there not exist any other method to show two files simultaneously? My professor is adamant that I implement this. I have spent days, but to no avail.

Comment: You should also beware that there are a number of old blog posts around about splitting the editor area - these all seem to be out of date and won't work on Eclipse 4.

Comment: Well you can read the source of the code that does the drag and drop split. This seems to be `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.SplitDropAgent2` however this requires a detailed knowledge of the Eclipse Application Model and looks horribly complicated.

Comment: I'll try to read it nevertheless. Meanwhile, I'll just tell him that what he is asking for is a gargantuan task. Thanks for your help, Greg.